# How is this possible from only one worker/PC?

Tags: mining, cpp-ethereum

So I was clicking around on the Ethermine.org site the other day to check out some folks's ETH performance levels and came across one that has me deeply pondering on how he is doing his mining.  I mean, how the hell is this guy mining ETH at 4-8GH/s with only one worker/machine?...

https://ethermine.org/miners/ccf6450724e3271a62f1fa751a381fb3c58e68f2/dashboard

I mean the most PCEI 1X slots I've even seen on one board is 12 and the fastest GPU cards out there mine around 50MH/s per GPU when heavily OCed, so how is this guy doing this?

Is he some how cheating the system or something possibly? Any thoughts on this folks?

Answer (score 2):

Right now that miner is getting over 500GH/s. One way to make it seem like you have one worker with that much hash power is by pretending you have one worker when you actually have many. The way you would do that is by having a server that sits between the public mining pool (like ethermine) and a private pool of mining rigs. The server reports to the public pool that it is a single worker, and the public pool sends work to the server. The server then distributes that work to its own private pool of workers, and sends their results back to the public pool.

Comment: Ah, ok!  Just making sure I wasn't missing out on something here.  Thanks for the explanation!